# Tracking a component property change through the Event System in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I can not fully understand the capabilities of the event system in Unity and when exactly it should be used. For example, such a situation. There is a *Canvas*, it has a *Canvas Group* component and it has an *Alpha property*. This property is changed through other scripts, we do not have an exact understanding of when exactly the *Alpha* property will change. Is it possible in this case to use only the event system and track the moment when exactly the *Alpha* change occurs? Or is it still impossible to do without *Update*? Thanks in advance for any help and hints.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the event system you're talking about is what UIToolkit uses. If it is, then it can be monitored by registering callbacks

> var propertyField = new PropertyField();
> // bind something...
> propertyField.RegisterCallback(ChangeEvent e => {something})

, and the latest version of Unity even supports listening for value changes directly by use

> RegisterValueChangeCallback